# Trying to put the Result set Values inside a Map

Tags: java, sql, resultset, sqlresultsetmapping

I'm trying to put the Result Set (DB Query Values) inside a LinkedHashMap>.

Every Iteration of row. The value is getting overriden while putting into DBMap.

```
<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> rowData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
<LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> dbData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
while (rset.next()) {

                    for (int col = 1; col < countCol+1; col++) {
                        String colname =rset.getMetaData().getColumnName(col);
                        rowData.put(colname, rset.getString(col));
                    }
                    int rowV = rset.getRow();
                    dbData.put(rowV, rowData);
}
```

This code is giving me the map of only the last row of the result set for all the keys in dbData Map.

Comment: I just posted the Required code which will answer my question here. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Please note the code you posted has extra enclosing `<>` in the first two lines. I'm assuming this is a typo, since based on your question I assumed your code passes compilation.

Comment: Thats Copy paste error :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the same `LinkedHashMap` instance (referenced by the `rowData` variable) multiple times in your outer `Map`. That's the reason the values of the final DB row overwrite all the previous values.

You have to create a new `LinkedHashMap` instance for each iteration of the `while` loop:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> dbData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
while (rset.next()) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> rowData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int col = 1; col < countCol+1; col++) {
        String colname =rset.getMetaData().getColumnName(col);
        rowData.put(colname, rset.getString(col));
    }
    int rowV = rset.getRow();
    dbData.put(rowV, rowData);
}
```

Comment: No idea who gave you the downvote. You give the code example, I gave an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you have only **one** rowData map - that gets updated with row data.

You have to create a **fresh** map for each row instead!

In other words: your current code creates **one** map, that gets updated for each "row" iteration. And in the end, you put that same map into your outer map.

Comment: And why? Seriously: a person who wants to deal with databases should be able to write that code within 2 minutes given the explanation.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked. I just declared the rowdata map inside result set loop. So it instantiate every iteration